# php extract function shows warnings

Tags: php, extract

when i am using extract it shows some warnings like **'PHP Warning:  extract() [function.extract]: First argument should be an array '**

following is the code

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');

ob_start();

global $mmb_core;
$data = unserialize(base64_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA));
$data =array($data);
$num  = extract($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, you either don't need line `$data =array($data);` or don't need to `unserialize`. Which one depends on the format of input. If input is serialized array, then it is enough to only `unserialize` it.
2. You need to make sure that `$data` is an associative array. Means that EACH element in it has a `string key` and that key fits in variable naming rules (e.g. does not start with number). If it is array, but not an associative array, this error will be produced.

Also this function validates whether these keys will overwrite already defined variables. So you need to use proper keys. I would use it this way

```
if(is_array($data)){
  $num = extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "data_");
}
```

That will prepend each key with `data_`. Also will work for not associative arrays making variables like `$data_0`, `$data_1` etc.

For more details you better refer to [official documentation](https://www.php.net/extract)

Comment: @Minu any example of incoming data that you fetch using `file_get_contents`? I need to see what kind of structure you are trying to parse.

Comment: actually it is a php file  in the plugin for wordpress. BUt when i used this it shows the warning..
`if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) 
{
        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');
    }
    ob_start();
    
    global $mmb_core;
    $data = unserialize(base64_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA));
   // $num  = extract($data);
    if(is_array($data)){
         $num = extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "data_");
    }`

Comment: @Minu, didn't get it. I meant that to say what exactly problem is i need to see what comes to `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. You could find it out by adding `echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;` next line after `file_get_contents`. Then you will be able to see the content you received right before the error message. Why do that? Because it is obviously problem of incoming data.

Comment: @Minu Also as you say this is a plugin for wordpress, i would suggest to check the requirements for this plugin such as: Wordpress version, other plugins this one may depend on, their versions etc.